# How to post json data in a domain/url and displays the results in browser?

Tags: json, perl

As a newbie in perl programming I still have troubles with it. I would like to ask how to post json data in a url and displays the results in a browser. I tried the script (below) and nothing happens; can't see data in the browser. I search for some codes to be tested but unluckily I didn't find any. I hope someone can advise me like if there is some codes I have to do. I'm pretty sure there is.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common qw(POST);

my $ua              = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $server_endpoint = 'https://..';

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( POST => $server_endpoint );
$req->header( 'content-type' => 'application/json' );

my $data = '{
{"value1" : "THEI3435J",
"value2" : "3453fdf",
"value3" : "Sep452"
}
} ';

$request->content($data);
my $resp = $ua->request($request);
print $request->as_string;

if ( $resp->is_success ) {
    my $message = $resp->decoded_content;
    print "$message\n";
} else {
    print "HTTP POST error code: ",    $resp->code,    "\n";
    print "HTTP POST error message: ", $resp->message, "\n";

}
```

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. You have `{ { "key" : "value" } }` which is wrong. You only need one pair of curly braces. The Perl code looks fine to me. And I assume by "in the browser" you mean when you access the server to look at stuff after you POSTed to it with that script, right?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid as you have an extra pair of braces.

If you're unsure how to format the data, use the [`JSON`](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON) module to do it for you:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use JSON;

my %hash = (
    value1 => "THEI3435J",
    value2 => "3453fdf",
    value3 => "Sep452",
);

print to_json( \%hash );
```

Outputs:

```
{"value1":"THEI3435J","value3":"Sep452","value2":"3453fdf"}
```